# How can I add a redirect for after my Facebook page is liked?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

i have a web site which has some Facebook like buttons like below

```
<div class="like-box">
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/samebirthday.officialpage" data-width="500" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
</div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>
  //facebook
  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ja_JP/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=700721206653864";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

and then, how can I add a redirect for after my Facebook page is liked?
i tried this one, but it didn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '700721206653864',
      status     : false, // check the login status upon init?
      cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
      function(response) {
        alert('liked!');
      }
    );

    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove',
      function(response) {
        alert('unliked!');
      }
    );
  };
</script>
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/ja_JP/all.js'></script>
```

Comment: Why are you loading the SDK two time unnecessarily?

Comment: BTW, your code is working for me; i can see the alerts on like/dislike

Comment: >Sahil Mittal i replaced the second one with first one.

Comment: really? as for me, the button doesn't appear... under rails4. is it caused of some functions of ruby on rails?

Comment: Check borwser's console for any error

Comment: sorry, I don't know why, but it works now! Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the subscribe event of as edge.create, this is the event fired when someone likes the page using a Like button. 
Add a redirect to it:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
      function(response) {
        window.location.href = 'http://the_URL_you_want';
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an EventListener on the  and add it to the chain!

`

var flike = document.getElementById('-------');

flike.addEventListener('click', function(){

// here you can do the redirection

}, false);
`